# How do I efficiently display image tiles in Unity 4.3 free

Tags: c#, unity, tilemap, tiles

I previously wrote a TileEngine with SFML that I would like to port to Unity3D 4.3, but have not found a way to draw a tile on the screen programmatically in Unity.

All I am looking for something akin to SFML's RenderTexture(), and **not** a plugin or something from the asset store.

I am using Unity 4.3's new 2D tools/workflow, and as such need a method that will work with the 2d viewport.

Comment: You can't. Rendering to textures ([RenderTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-RenderTexture.html)) is a Unity Pro feature.

Comment: Seriously? Is there no other way I can do a tile engine in unity free?

Comment: Render-to-texture sounds like a bad idea for a tile engine. I would do it by making a grid of polygons with different texturing on each polygon.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, an example on how to do it. I used RenderTexture in SFML, but I want to know what would be best in unity for a tile engine, and a pointer in the right direction on how to get started.

Comment: You should edit your question then, because it asks about "draw[ing] a texture programmatically." The answer to that question is "you can't"; any other question is, well, not what the question says.

Comment: Take a look at my answer below, you can draw the texture/tile on the screen via setting up a mesh programmatically.

Comment: Would GUI.DrawTexture() and GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords() be relevant? They let you draw an arbitrary rectangle of texture to the screen, without setting up mesh vertices or materials manually.

Comment: re setting up a mesh programmatically: I wouldn't call that "drawing a texture", I would call that "displaying tile images". And if you think that distinction is just semantics, well the specific terminology matters here. For example, bummzack already pointed out that "RenderTexture" means something specific.

Comment: If you actually read my question, you'll note that I previously wrote a TileEngine that I would like to port to Unity and don't know how to draw/display/render/align pixels to form a Tile on the screen. Now, surely from that you should be able to deduce that I am new to Unity and don't know how to achieve my goal? I am **deeply** sorry my syntax didn't meet your exacting standards, but perhaps next time you attempt to "help" a beginner, you could cut the person some slack? It is hilariously ironic however, that unbeknown to me, Unity has a method named Gui.DRAWTEXTURE.

Comment: I would avoid GUI.DrawTexture() as well; because the immediate mode GUI in Unity is pretty inefficient, they are building a new GUI system (about to release it actually, in version 4.6). As for you feeling like I was attacking you, hey man I'm sorry you took my help that way. I was simply trying to point you to the correct way to do things; terminology matters because looking up, say, "how to draw textures in unity" leads to not-great approaches like GUI.DrawTexture()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two guides programmatically create squares using a mesh, which is along the lines of what I was looking for.

http://studentgamedev.blogspot.no/2013/08/unity-voxel-tutorial-part-1-generating.html
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbghT7MmckI4qGA0Wm_TZS8LVrqS47I9R